# IP rights for using quotes?

Tags: intellectual-property

If someone sells something associated to a famous quote from someone or something, how would they ensure that they are within the law to be able to do so? I'm very curious about how this would work out as I have recently seen a lot of tattoo artists' that offer bespoke designs for their clients who request such things...